# Draw ellipse/hyperbola in swift and sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ellipse

I'm making an app in Xcode that involves planets orbiting stars, and I can get them to do so with radial gravity fields, but now I would like to draw their orbits. How can I draw ellipses and hyperbolas in swift? I can't just use an image, because each orbit has a different equation. A more general question would be how to draw a graph in polar coordinates, if that's easier to answer. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you know how to convert polar to cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Even if you know how to draw an ellipse, finding the ellipse equation that'll match the behavior of SpriteKit's physics system — before that system runs — sounds like a difficult problem. Maybe you can fake it instead? That is, draw the orbit as the planet traverses it by tracing out the path the planet has already covered.

Comment: @Abizern Yes, I do know how to convert.

Comment: @rickster I think I can figure out the correct equation. I know orbital mechanics, so it's really just a matter of converting the equations to sprite kit's units of velocity and acceleration.

Comment: Getting real-physics predictions to match up to SpriteKit-physics results can often be harder than just knowing the appropriate real-physics stuff. :) (For one thing, IIRC SpriteKit uses a variable time step based on frame rate.)

Comment: @rickster Okay, in that case, how would I trace out the path that the planet has covered?

Comment: A good answer to that will require writing some code, and I'm posting from my phone right now. Stay tuned. But here's the gist: sample positions of your planet at intervals (in `didSimulatePhysics` maybe), and either place nodes at those points or create a shape node from a path based on those points.

Comment: Does it need to have other special properties? Or can you just create a CGPath and run an SKAction on the node to move along the path? If so, creating a CGPath ellipse or parabola is quite frankly easy (i'll refrain from posting code until I know this is a feasible solution)